# Vector Not Drawing Properly on API v23

Tags: android, svg, vector-graphics

I'm using `support-vector-drawable` to provide vector drawable support in a backwards compatible manner in my Android app, minSdk version 18.

I have a few images that display fine on v18, v19, v21, v22, and v24. However, on API v23 specifically they don't draw properly. What's the fix/workaround for this?

Comment: Can you explain what "not drawing properly" means?

Comment: The graphic does not look as intended on API 23, but it does on all other API versions.

Comment: I assume in API 23 it uses the built in vector support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an AppCompat issue for api 23 that you can find here: [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=215262)

- Nothing to do than to star the issue and wait for a future release of AppCompat. (Using 24.2.1 for now and it's not drawn correctly)
- Possible workaround is to go back to PNG instead of vectors (not a great news unfortunately)

[image: Android Issue]